# Thymeleaf and Spring Boot doesn't show image

Tags: java, image, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Do my Spring Boot app with thymeleaf and instead of image I see only icon of image. How can I fix this?
Image in static->images folder

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr th:each="message : ${messages}">
        <td th:text="${message.id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${message.text}"></td>
        <td th:text="${message.tag}"></td>
        <td><img th:src="@{/images/thymeleaf.png}"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: give your webmvc configuration

Comment: `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file://" + uploadPath + "/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");}`

Answer (score 0):

Use configuration like this.

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("file:resources/","file:images/","file:" + uploadPath + "/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
}
```

add all location from where you want to show image.
dont use **/** after **file:**